# Ruby NoMethod Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to solve simple task: find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers:

```
def is_palindrome?(number)
  number = number.to_s
  while number.length > 1
    return false if number[0] != number[number.length - 1]
    number = number[1, number.length - 2]
  end
  return true
end

def find_max_palindrome
  x, y, z = 100
  max = 1
  while x < 1000
    while y < 1000
      z = x * y
      max = z if is_palindrome?(z)
      y += 1
    end
    x += 1
  end
  return max
end

puts find_max_palindrome
```

But something goes wrong:

```
004.rb:14:in `find_max_palindrome': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from 004.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone tell me where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this one

```
x, y, z = 100
 => 100 
2.4.0 :002 > x
 => 100 
2.4.0 :003 > y
 => nil 
2.4.0 :004 > z
 => nil
```

You mean something like

```
x = y = z = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x, y, z = 100
```

doesn't assign `100` to `x`, `y` and `z`. It only assigns `100` to `x`. This makes the line `while y < 1000` raise an error, because `y` is still `nil`.

Change that line to:

```
x = y = z = 100
```

Or to the following which I think is easier to read and to understand:

```
x = 100
y = 100
z = 100
```